# TI CC2530 breakout board ali express

Tags: zigbee

recently I bought a little pcb with TI CC2530 ZigBee Chip and antenna on it on ali express with antenna. Here the link:

http://de.aliexpress.com/store/product/free-shipping-4pcs-2-4G-IEEE-802-15-4-CC2530-Low-Power-Zigbee-Module/605000_560834881.html?storeId=605000&af=16644&dp=boxiDscq0yQ.2Ne3qrstP3z_V5jlMZTmokQK7flmtZCb&cn=9263&cv=15091&afref=4551

Does anybody know which ZigBee Stack is installed on the chip and whether there is a possibility to install another Stack?

Thanks in advance,

Florian

Answer (score 0):

Which varsion of the Z-Stack was installed on this board - nobody kwowns.

For install new version of Z-Stack and your developed app on it stack, you need [CC Debugger](http://de.aliexpress.com/item/CC-Debugger-ZIGBEE-emulator-support-online-upgrade-original-shell-original-quality/32229661226.html?spm=2114.010208.3.2.N6TVaa&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_0,searchweb201602_4_10048_10047_10037_10017_405_507_10046_10045_10032,searchweb201603_1&btsid=e7d644d6-25cf-4e43-b926-57df94bbea85) for flashing and debugging.

For quick start see [CC Debugger User Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru197h/swru197h.pdf)

For future - it's a bad idea to buy chineese non-original and noname development kits because it is too hard for quick start and learning. Better buy original kits with brilliant documentation and good ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are totally right in saying it costs time to have a system with less documentation. But if every one would share his experience with those boards we can succeed.

I could already flash the chip with CC Debugger, so a known Z-Stack is installed. But I cannot talk with the chip (ZNP) from my application processor via SPI. Really strange. Maybe I have some mistakes in my code. But actually the SPI trace looks ok.

Comment: My next step would be to solder an original CC2530 chip on this breakoutboard. Maybe it is really the non-original chip. 
I suppose I am not the first person who played around with such breakout board. So would be great if anybody can tell me his experiences.